# How to use a code node to list all of the datasets in a .egp file using SAS EG?

Tags: sas

I want to get a list all of the datasets to enter them into an array.

I could then feed each item in the array into a macro to prevent me from having to do a repetitive task.

Comment: I would try to avoid making code EG-dependent.  If all of these datasets are in a certain library, you can get a list from dictionary.tables.  You could also use dataset naming conventions.  The more dependent the solution is on the IDE (EG), the more changes you will need to make if you ever change to another IDE (e.g. SAS Studio), or run code as a batch job.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'all of the datasets in a .egp file'. EGP files don't actually have data sets, but they connect to libraries that do and they generate files that go to the work library. They can also delete files. So it depends on exactly how you define that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall EG having that level of introspection available to submitted code.  However, an add-in tool can be programmed (as a Windows .dll) and the add-in will be able to examine the client (EG), project and other meta information not available to code submitted by the client (i.e. your SAS code that will run either locally or remotely depending on server settings of the active profile)

A link to reference documentation (SAS.EG.ADDins) and other add-in material can be found at http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/release30/addins/

The SAS.EG.Addins help states

> **Services Supplied by the Host Application (*to the Add-in*)**
>
> The following interfaces
>   surface information and services that are supplied by the host
>   application (for example, SAS Enterprise Guide and the SAS Add-in for
>   Microsoft Office). These are the interfaces that are supported by all
>   host applications:
>
> - ISASTaskConsumer
>    Provides information about what the application
>     supports and access to other supported interfaces. Also provides
>     access to options specific to the particular instance of the add-in.
> - ISASTaskData, ISASTaskDataAccessor, ISASTaskDataColumn 
>   Provides access
>     to data services.
>
> These are the interfaces that might be supported by a given host
>   application. If your add-in code takes advantage of any of these
>   interfaces/services, you should include checks to ensure that an
>   interface is supported before you attempt to use it.
>
> - ISASTaskSubmit 
>   Allows your add-in to submit a SAS program for
>     processing while the user interact with your user interface.
> - ISASTaskUtilities 
>   Supplies utility methods for use by your add-in.